# Chaining ImageMagick together to set background to white and split files into squares

Tags: imagemagick, command-line-interface, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to resize an image to a 3x2 crop and then split the image up into 6 square subimages. The following two commands using a temp file works:

`>  magick rose: -size 84x55 canvas: +swap -gravity center -composite  rose.jpg`

`>  magick rose.jpg -crop 3x2@ +repage cropped/rose@_%d.gif`

This results in the desired of 6 images of sizes 28x28 and 28x27 (square).

I tried to make this one command:

`>   magick rose: -size 84x55 canvas: +swap -gravity center -composite  -crop 3x2@ +repage cropped/rose@_%d.gif`

But when I run the composite command, the cropped images are **not** square. It results in 6 images of sizes 55x41, 56x41, 55x50 not the desired result.

Comment: I just read your question again - why do you think the cropped images should be square please? What dimensions you expect them to have exactly?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I am trying to resize my image into 3x2 crop and then break that image with the white padding into 6 squares. This is a bit forced with ```rose:``` because it is already a 3x2 crop.

Comment: If you run the two  separate commands you will get 6 images of size of sizes 28x28 and 28x27 (square). This is what I want. My second joined command generate 6 images of sizes 55x41, 56x41, 55x50 (this is not what I want).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you got that syntax from, but I think this does what you want:

```
magick rose: -gravity center -background white -extent 84x55 -crop 3x2@ +repage cropped/rose-%d.gif
```

Comment: The results of this answer is exactly the same results from my attempt at joining the two methods: I get 6 images of sizes 55x41, 56x41, 55x50 not the desired result 6 images of size of sizes 28x28 and 28x27 (square) that I am getting in running the separate two commands.